# Oauth 2 in kmail in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: email, gmail, kmail, email-client, oauth

I am trying to connect gmail using kmail from Ubuntu 16.04, but it is not connecting. After doing google search I came to know that, gmail using oauth 2 for authentication of desktop app. Is there a way I can use oauth in kmail for gmail in Ubuntu 16.04. I don't want to enable 'less secure access' in gmail.

Comment: here's a three tutorial describing how to do that 
1)https://www.maketecheasier.com/check-gmail-account-with-kmail/
2)https://userbase.kde.org/Working_with_GMail
3)https://tuxicity.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/howto-set-up-gmail-in-kmail-mailclient-in-kde/

Comment: All this methods describe how to configure IMAP and SMTP. I have tried same method previously and  I can configure gmail. But problem is, if I only use this methods then I have to enable access to less secure app in gamil. I don't want to do that.  I also want kmail to ask for oauth. How is it possible?